# Packagename for libQt5XcbQpa.so.5

Tags: vpn

What is the best way to tell what package name that installed libQt5XcbQpa.so.5?   I am having a application failure segfault at 18 ip 00007f6bb61e0fa2 sp 00007ffc47dead60 error 4 in libQt5XcbQpa.so.5[7f6bb617c000+15b000].

I have a feeling the vendor going to want to deinstall the package in order to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The file is in the package `libqt5gui5-gle`. Check here http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libqt5gui5-gles/filelist

Normally if you know the file location you can check which package this file belongs to by using the command

```
dpkg -S file-location
```